# Combining terms in a conditionally convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I am aware that one is unable to rearrange terms in a conditionally convergent series. But, take a conditionally convergent series, say

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$$

and group terms with a stride of two to produce

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n}.$$

With this particular series, even if I take the absolute value of the terms, it converges to the same value. Does this imply the reformatted series is absolutely convergent, and that I can validly rearrange its terms arbitrarily?

Comment: What do you mean “the same convergence?”

Comment: With every conditionally convergent series, there are some rearrangements that change the sum and some other rearrangements that do not change the sum. The fact that some rearrangements do not change the sum does not mean that there are no others that do change the sum.

Comment: Yes, this shows that some rearrangements do converge to the same value.

Comment: It seems that the word rearrangement is being used in a broad sense. I prefer to distinguish between grouping consecutive terms and more general rearrangements in which the order of summing terms is not preserved.  In the case at hand, I would prefer the term grouping to rearranging.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews As in converge to the same value. I have edited the post to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the new series you have created is absolutely convergent, and rearranging its terms will not change its value. Note however, that the set of terms of the new series,
$$
b_n = \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}, 
$$
is not the same as the set of terms of the old series, so this is not a rearrangement of the old series in the strict sense.

Comment: Well, it can be represented as a re-arrangement of the original series, so it says if you rearrange the original series so that you keep together consecutive odd-even  pairs, you get the same sum.

Comment: Yes, it certainly can be. I was just trying to emphasize the point that the actual terms of the new sequence were different than the old one, but your point is also helpful.

Comment: It seems that the word rearrangement is being used in a broad sense.  I prefer to distinguish between grouping consecutive terms and more general rearrangements in which the order of summing terms is not preserved.